# Ubuntu keyboard LEFT CTRL + shift is not working

Tags: 16.04, 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

when try to navigate using the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> it doesn't work but when using the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> it works fine so when I trace the problem is when I press the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> is not working only the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

I tried the tweak solution but still  not working.

Comment: Maybe your keyboard is defective?

Comment: the left ctrl works alone perfect but when using the left ctrl and shift together it doesn't work

Comment: Please test another keyboard on your PC, or test your keyboard on another PC. If you aren't able to do these tests, let us know too.

Comment: I tested it ad still get the same issue

Comment: Please open a console and run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`. Select your keyboard model (usually `Generic 105-key PC (intl.)` works). After that select your country of origin for your keyboard. Now select the layout, if you have no idea what layout you need, select the very first layout at the top. Select the default value for `Key to function as AltGr:`. Select `No compose key` as your `Compose key:` - setting. Test the keyboard settings, maybe a reboot is needed.

Comment: method for toggling  between national and Latin what should id  choose

Comment: Now the left ctrl work with the right shift but not with the left shift

Comment: I have this exact problem in Manjaro.
LC+RS works.
RC+LS works.
RC+RS works.
LC+LS does now work.